# Synchronization of 3 threads in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have 3 threads to download data from the internet.

```
func thread1() {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        // do something from json
    }
}

func thread2() {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        // do something from json
    }
}

func thread3() {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        // download img
    }
}


func finishFunction() {
    print("Finish")
}
```

I would like to start the finishFunction function after finishing threads 1, 2 and 3. How can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, you don't wrap function bodies in `sync`/`async` calls. It's better to just have the function do what it does, and then give callers the flexibility to hand them off to dispatch, with the QoS they want, on the queue they want, and with any other flags they want.

```
func doSomethingFromJSON1() {}
func doSomethingFromJSON2() {}
func downloadImage() {}

func doItAll() {
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        doSomethingFromJSON1()
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        doSomethingFromJSON2()
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.enter()
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        downloadImage()
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .global) {
        finishFunction()
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but your enter() and leave() calls don't balance out.

Comment: Your answer help my app load data very fast :D. But how many queue be allowed in 1 dispatch group?

Comment: @tdtkien The dispatch queue doesn't care, it doesn't even know about queues. As many times as it's entered, it has to be exited. That's all it knows about.

Comment: Wow, I would have used a semaphore for this. But this is cleaner and conventional. Full documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup

Comment: @Alexander a query I have though, what if `doSomethingFromJSON1()`, `doSomethingFromJSON2()`, `doSomethingFromJSON3()` where each async calls that take callbacks. Would this still work to place the `dispatchGroup.leave()` within the callback. In other words would `DispatchQueue.global().async` still work if the encapsulated call itself is async ?

Comment: @Alexander I've actually answered myself lol, in the case described above- there wouldn't be any need to wrap each of those three functions in `DispatchQueue.global().async` as they are already async. Just place the leave() within the callback. Need more coffee :p